# Cordova android build duration time takes too much time

Tags: android, cordova

Since I've been using phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner for my Cordova app, android build time increased from 30 second to 9 min.

Here is the build processing of my app:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\www\camera>cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Emad Emami\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_77
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:prepareBarcodescannerLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Alpha2Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl
:compileDebugRenderscript
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources
:mergeDebugResources
:processDebugManifest
:processDebugResources
:generateDebugSources
:compileDebugJavaWithJavacNote: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugSources
:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:validateDebugSigning
:packageDebug
:zipalignDebug
:assembleDebug
:cdvBuildDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 9 mins 17.768 secs
Built the following apk(s):
        C:/xampp/htdocs/www/camera/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debu
g.apk
```

Most delay time is on this part:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\www\camera>cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Emad Emami\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_77
```

Can any one tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: Are you using latest version of cordova? Could you monitor your system performance while performing this operation? Could be a performance issue with you system as well.

Comment: It's cordova 6.1.1 and it was working like a charm untill phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner installed on the app. how can I monitor my system performance?

Comment: Tried out on my newly created project, works fine. Initially got error related to android compatibility but after updating "Android Support Repository" in Android SDK, it works fine. Compiles in 33 secs. Have following plugins in my project: cordova-plugin-compat, cordova-plugin-facebook4, cordova-plugin-whitelist, phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner Ensure that you dont have any other plugins which may be creating the problem.

Comment: cordova-plugin-camera & cordova-plugin-compat & cordova-plugin-device & cordova-plugin-file & cordova-plugin-file-transfer & phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner & cordova-plugin-whitelist are all plugins in my app and I've been tested all plugins. this issue appear just when phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner is installed.

Comment: Could you create a barebone project only with phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner and try building it to isolate the issue?

Comment: I found something... It depends on internet connection. it seems this plugin is using some library from internet because when I disconnect it from internet android building process time decrease to 30 sec again also app work fine. How can I figure it out why this plugin using online library and how to avoid it?

Comment: I guess downloading external library is an one time task. The plugin itself will be cache after first install. So apart from first install, it should not take much time and have checked the same. Can you try npm cache clean once and try installing the plugin afresh